# The procedure entry point <function> could not be located in the dynamic link library <dll>

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have converted all of the VB.NET DLL declarations

```
Declare Function SFileOpenArchive Lib "Storm.dll" Alias "#266" (ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwPriority As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByRef hMPQ As Integer) As Boolean
```

over into Delphi.

```
function SFileOpenArchive(lpFileName: String; dwPriority, dwFlags, hMPQ: Integer): Boolean; stdcall; external 'Storm.dll';
```

However, when I call the functions and compile the program I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point SFileOpenArchive could not be located in the dynamic link library Storm.dll.

I have ensured that:

1. the DLL is stored in the same directory as the application
2. the functions I have declared exist (I was given the source code which was coded in VB.NET)

What can I do to fix this error?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following problems that I can see:

1. The function has been exported by ordinal rather than name. You need to specify the ordinal in your Delphi code.
2. The first parameter should be PAnsiChar rather than a Delphi string. The VB code uses string to instruct the marshaller to pass a null-terminated string. As a rule of thumb, it's almost always a mistake to include a Delphi managed stype like string in a DLL import or export.
3. The final parameter is passed by reference. That's a Delphi var parameter.
4. The return value should be BOOL, I think, but that probably won't be causing you trouble.

Put it all together like this:

```
function SFileOpenArchive(lpFileName: PAnsiChar; 
    dwPriority, dwFlags: Integer; var hMPQ: Integer): BOOL; 
    stdcall; external 'Storm.dll' index 266;
```

Note that I'm not 100% sure that the text encoding is ANSI. However, the main blockage for you was the ordinal import. I hope I've cleared that for you. I trust you can resolve the remaining details.

Comment: The last parameter is probably a var.

Comment: So the `index` keyword is used for ordinals, but what if the function has been exported by string?

Comment: Then it would look like this: `external 'Storm.dll' name 'functionname';` and the `name` part is optional if the exported name is the same as the name you used in your import. So in your case, the code in your question is equivalent to `external 'Storm.dll' name 'SFileOpenArchive';`

Comment: When I go to compile, Delphi says that `hMPQ` is an "undeclared identifier" when I use the function that I've mentioned in my original post. Does this mean I have to globally declare `hMPQ` under `var` section?

Comment: `hMPQ` is a `var` parameter. So, you need to declare a variable and pass that variable to the procedure. I've no idea whether it needs to be initialised or not. You have the documentation to the library and I don't.