# Why do some DLL files need an additional .lib file for linking?

Tags: qt, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a question about library linking and .lib files...

this is the context:

- OS = Windows
- IDE = QT

I have created a DLL: MyLib.dll.
To use that library in my QT project, I only have to include an include path, a link to the library and use the header files:

```
LIBS += "C:\myPath\MyLib.dll"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\myPath"
HEADERS += \
    ../myPath/MyLib_global.h \
    ../myPath/mylib.h
```

I am using a third party dll in my project: third.dll
If I do the same as in the above example, it does not work:

```
LIBS += "C:\myPath\third.dll"
```

The third party DLL comes with a .lib file "third.lib", which I apparently need to use together with the DLL.

Why is that? Why do some DLL libraries need a .lib file but other DLL libraries don't? 
Could it be that the .lib is a static library accessing the DLL?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lib file is an import library file, which allows the final executable to contain an import address table (IAT) by which all DLL function calls are referenced. Basically, allowing the functions to be looked up.

You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries).

To have Qt generate the lib, add this to the .pro: -

```
CONFIG+= staticlib
```

[Here's](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) some documentation on how to create libraries.

Comment: thanks @Merlin069 for your answer. that clarifies it! One thing: when I created myLib.dll, I did not see any way to generate a lib file with the DLL file. is that on option when building the DLL? Also, all function calls in my DLL seem to be accessible without the lib file too. Is that not what the .lib file is supposed to allow? thanks

Comment: There should be an import library by default.

Comment: There's likely to be a setting in your IDE to create the lib file, if it's not already generating one. As far as I understand it, without the lib file, you can load the dll separately and call functions, but the lib is required if you want to build an executable with static libraries.

Comment: I've updated the answer for how to generate and use the lib in Qt.

Comment: thanks @Merlin069 That link was very useful. According to the article, the whole business of lib or not lib depends on the compiler used. If the libraries were compiled using MSCV2010 you will need the .lib file. But if the library was compiled using MinGW there is no .lib at all. In my case, this explains why one library has .lib and the other one does not have one; we used different compilers.

Comment: CONFIG+= staticlib will create a static library instead of a DLL, but it is not related to the .lib file i think

Comment: Check out the last comment in this thread: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-5915.html

Comment: Yes, that it is. As the comment reads "The LIBS was required (in MSVC2010) as the "difference" of mingw."

Comment: Of course. Gonna do it now. Thanks for your great help @Merlin069

Answer (score 13):

My answer may not be specific to the context but would be useful to most developers asking the same question. This was answered by Anthony Williams

[What is inside .lib file of Static library, Statically linked dynamic library and dynamically linked dynamic library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250467/what-is-inside-lib-file-of-static-library-statically-linked-dynamic-library-an)

> You don't need a .lib file to use a dynamic library, but without one
>   you cannot treat functions from the DLL as normal functions in your
>   code. Instead you must manually call LoadLibrary to load the DLL (and
>   FreeLibrary when you're done), and GetProcAddress to obtain the
>   address of the function or data item in the DLL. You must then cast
>   the returned address to an appropriate pointer-to-function in order to
>   use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why is that? Why do some DLL libraries need a .lib file but other DLL libraries don't?

There are two types in linking dll :
Load time dynamic linking [ Implicit ]
Run time dynamic linking [ Explicit ]

If you using run time dynamic linking of dll the .lib is not used
But, for load time dynamic linking of dll the.lib file is used