# Opencv 3.2.0 .dll missing despite static linking

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

I am trying to use a program utilizing OpenCV on a PC that does not have OpenCV installed. Trying to start the program results in the following error:

"This program can't start because opencv_world320.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem."

Now I know this normally happens if the correct libraries are not linked or linking was not static but as pre-built OpenCV 3.2 only uses a single library and after double checking that runtime library is set to /MT in VS2015 I have no idea why this error is still present.

Looking at the built .exe file in a PE Analyzer also shows that opencv_world320.dll is still listed as an import.

How to fix this?

Comment: For anyone running into the same problem, here is how I did it after Miki's pointers:
http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV 3.2 prebuild only provides x64 **dynamic** libraries for vc14.

The `.lib` you're trying to link (in subfolder `x64\vc14\lib`) is a *import* library, that contains the symbols to allow the linker to link to the `dll`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913691/dll-and-lib-files-what-and-why) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421693/why-are-lib-files-beasts-of-such-a-duplicitous-nature) for further details on the matter.

In practice, if you want to static link to OpenCV, you need to rebuild it. You'll find the static libraries in subfolder `x64\vc14\staticlib`.

Comment: The `staticlib` folder is not provided anymore with 3.2 as far as I can see. Thanks a lot though, I will look into it.

Comment: It'll be there after you recompile opencv with static linkage

Comment: @Miki , I am using windows, I compiled OpenCV 3.4.2 in CMAKE with the flag "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS " Off, now I should open OpenCV.sln , and rebuild all ? In OpenCV 3.4.2 It creates folder named "lib" with all the libs, is it the same one as x64\vc14\staticlib ?