# Expat XML parser (static link, dll error (missing define? )

Tags: c++, c, xml

I usually program in Ubuntu so I'm having a little bit of problem working in Visual Studio 2013 in Windows. I'm using a library for xml parsing expat, I'm using it statically and I'm having problems, when running the program I get the following error when *executing* (not compilation or linker error) :

"The program can't start because libexpat.dll is missing from your computer(...)."

The problem is that I'm running the library statically so there shouldn't be dll problems, my best guess is that I'm missing a define to indicate static link. I tried using #define XML_STATIC but no do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are currently linking to an import library instead of a static library. Try copying the libexpat.dll to the same folder your programs .exe file is located.

You could find more information in these already answered questions:

[DLL and LIB files - what and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913691/dll-and-lib-files-what-and-why)

[c static linking to lib and still requesting DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240737/c-static-linking-to-lib-and-still-requesting-dll)