# DLL not found despite static linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, static-linking

I have `bass.lib`, `bass_fx.lib` and `zlib.lib` in my `Library` folders and `Additional Dependencies` in my project.
[image]

[image]
But when I run my program, it complains it can't find `bass.dll`, `bass_fx.dll` and `zlib.dll`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240737/static-linking-to-lib-and-still-requesting-dll

Comment: @DhirajWishal How do I know whether a .lib file is a export table or an actual library? Just the file size?

Comment: I,m not that familiar with this topic but these links might help: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)

Comment: @Raildex See [know if .lib is static or import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402586/know-if-lib-is-static-or-import).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link statically, first you have to make sure that the *.lib's you have are really static and not dynamic libraries (which seems to be the case).

You can use `dumpbin` from visual studio command line tools, to verify what's inside those .libs.

Comment: I know how DLL linking works, but I want to link the specific libraries statically.

Comment: I think what OP is trying to ask is that he s trying to link it statically but the application is requesting a .dll file.

Comment: If you exe complains it cannot find dll's - in that case you're not linking statically